# Visualizing data techniques for groups of data using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization, venn-diagram

I have a list of applications and the servers that are providing access to these applications, there are a large number of crossovers, For Example:

```
Servers 01-09 provide App A, App, B
Servers 05-09 provide App C
Servers 10-14 also provide App A
```

Currently I have drawn on a sheet of paper a lot of boxes with the list of servers and their apps, grouped into servers running the same app. using the example above: A box labelled 01-09 with App A and App B written inside and overlapping another box labelled 05-09 with App C written in it.

I wanted to transfer this into a visualization provided by `d3` (I am also learning `d3`) that I can show on a website. I had in mind a kind of super `venn diagram` or something? The goal is to easily see the groups of servers running the same applications.

Has anyone else had this kind of visualization problem - what techniques did you use? what does `d3` have built in that could be used in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the easiest way to do this is in a table because you have only two dimensions:

```
| Server | App A | App B | App C |
|--------------------------------|
| 01     |   X   |       |       |
| 02     |       |       |       |
etc
```

If you're set on d3.js (quite reasonable), I would use a [Co-occurrence graph](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/) with servers vertically and apps horizontally.

Alternatively, you could try [labelled force](http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729) with apps having one shape and servers having another. I don't think that's as readable as a table!

Comment: The number of servers and applications would render having a table for each server un-readable at a glance, I like the look of the Co-occurence graph, especially as you can sort it into clusters - the visualization effect i am looking for. I agree with the labelled force graph not being readable.

Comment: You could argue though that there are more than 2 dimensions (the number of servers running the same app - i.e 01-09 running App A could be grouped with the number of servers acting as another dimension)?

Comment: Ah. If you have a lot of these then filtering against a table is good. What's also nice about a table is that you can easily CSV export for those who like to explore data using Excel. Co-occurrence can do that too (and is my favourite solution).
Re: dimensions: I understand them as a measure in one direction. You have two measures: server and app. Grouping creates a "sub manifold" but it's still a single dimension.

Comment: Also, I think co-occurrence is good for learning to `d3.js` because it's not one of the really complex ones. You'll probably get your result really quickly, which will allow you to get feedback from others and iterate quickly.

Answer (score 1):

One option in this case is to visualize using a Bipartite graph.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph

Bipartite graphs are graphs where you have two distinct sets of nodes where there are no edges between members of the same set and all edges are from one set to another.

Here you can have applications (A, B, C etc.) as one set and the servers (01-14) as another set.

Further, it depends what you want to achieve with this visualization. For example, if your intent is to show and compare server load of the number of servers running an application, you can use the size of nodes to encode that.